# Remove Function at Preprocessor Time

Tags: compilation-errors, functions, c-preprocessor

I have a single function for debugging messages, used through all the project. When `KEYDEBUG` is defined as `1` or `0`, the function is enabled or disabled as required.

```cpp
#define KEYDEBUG 0

void debugging(int var){
   #if KEYDEBUG
   //Assert
   #endif
}
```

When checking the compiler, the variable `var` raises a warning `-Wunused-parameter`. 
How should remove this warning just at this part of the project?
Or which other alternative for using debugging code and removing it from memory for production release?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you do not use the entire body, so you can use a macro.

This way the code when KEYDEBUG is 0, will be like the complete function would not exist (except for the void cast, see below).

```
#include "assert.h"

#define KEYDEBUG 0

#ifndef KEYDEBUG
#define debugging(x) void(x);
#endif


void debugging(int var){
   assert(var);
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  debugging(1);
}
```

---

The information below is for not using the function parameter, but keep the function (in case you have code in your function that also does something when KEYDEBUG is 0.

**Unused attribute**

The cleanest way I could find is using the unused attribute:

```
#if KEYDEBUG
   void debugging(__attribute__((unused)) int var){
      //Assert
#else
   void debugging(int var){
      //Assert
#endif
   }
```

or if you prefer better readability:

```
#if KEYDEBUG
   void debugging(__attribute__((unused)) int var){
      //Assert
   }
#else
   void debugging(int var){
      //Assert
   }
#endif
```

**Cast to void**

Less clean but does the job:

```
void debugging(int var){
   #if KEYDEBUG
      //Assert
   #else
      (void) var; // prevent unused parameter warning
   #endif
}
```

**Macros/Parameter**

It's not easy to remove the variable since it's used in a function and will be called from many places probably. You could maybe you use a macro but that gets messy soon.

This solution works, and afaik the compiler will optimize the code out (if not , it will cost very less anyway).

Comment: It is possible to remove absolutely the debugging function and its calls without touching the `debugging` calls?

Comment: Not fully, well in the macro I defined, the function call is replaced by a void cast, so this is not a function, and you don't have to touch the `debugging` calls.